# Парсинг строк Oracle

Tags: oracle

Help!

Предположим, есть таблица из двух столбцов. Значения строки в первом столбце выглядят по типу:

```
слово1/слово2/слово3/.../слово N
```

во втором:

```
число1/число2/число3/.../число N
```

Необходимо запарсить строки так, чтоб каждая такая строка разбилась на `N` строк в виде:

```
слово1  число1  
слово2  число2  
слово3  число3  
...  
словоN  числоN
```

Comment: Вы уже поробовали, но не работает? Опубликуйте пожалуйста вашу выборку и тестовые данные в виде - `select ... from dual`.

Comment: Почему именно "слово1" сопоставлено в результате с "число1"? По порядку в начальных данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На случай если строк исходных данных несколько и у них есть некий уникальный ID:

```
 select id,
        regexp_substr(word, '[^/]+',1,level) w,
        regexp_substr(num , '[^/]+',1,level)
   from test
connect by id=prior id and prior dbms_random.value is not null
       and (   regexp_substr(word, '[^/]+',1,level) is not null
            or regexp_substr(num , '[^/]+',1,level) is not null
           )
```

Если строка всего одна, то в connect by конечно не понадобится сверять ID (что бы не переклеить слова с номерами из разных записей) и условие с dbms_random то же не понадобится.