# Распарсить строку по пробелам в PL/SQL

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, plsql

Добрый день.
Подскажите, как лучше распарсить строку по пробелам, чтобы вышло то количество слов, сколько пробелов.

```
declare
result_string varchar2(255) := 'CHURCH OF ENGLAND 104';
res varchar2(255);
begin
for i in 1 .. regexp_count(result_string, '\w+ ', 1, 'i')loop
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
regexp_substr(result_string, '\w+', regexp_instr(result_string, ' ', i))
);
end loop;
end;
```

В результат ожидаю:

```
CHURCH
OF
ENGLAND
```

Спасибо

Comment: Очень странная постановка задачи. Столько слов, сколько пробелов. А если строка начинается с 3х пробелов, а слова только 2? Или между словами было бы 2 пробела, то тогда `104` попало бы в результат?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Парсинг строк Oracle](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583267/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-oracle)

Comment: В начале пробелов не будет, примите за эталон ту строку, что приведена в коде. Другого не будет. Нужно вывести слова по отдельности, разделенные пробелом.

Comment: А что вас не устраивает в вашем коде? И я так и не понял, `104` то должно в результат попасть или нет?

Comment: Меня не устраивает в коде то, что он выводит только одно значение сейчас - OF. Я хочу, чтобы выводил три слова по следующей логике:
выводим все до первого пробела, дальше от первого пробела выводим все до следующего и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тут (ссылка)](http://apps-oracle.ru/get_sub_string-2/) есть несколько примеров извлечение подстрок из строки с разделителями. Вот, например, через `connect` + `instr`:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, level) str
 FROM ( SELECT 'CHURCH OF ENGLAND 104' str FROM dual ) t
 CONNECT BY instr(str, ' ', 1, level - 1) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за участие, решил следующим образом

```
declare
result_string varchar2(255) := 'CHURCH OF ENGLAND 104';
res varchar2(255);
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(regexp_count(result_string, '\w+(\s|$)', 1, 'i'));
for i in 1 .. regexp_count(result_string, '\w+(\s|$)', 1, 'i') loop
  --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(regexp_substr(result_string, '\w+', regexp_instr(result_string, ' ', i)));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(regexp_replace(result_string, '(\w+)(\s|&)(.*)', '\1'));
  result_string := regexp_replace(result_string, '(\w+)(\s|&)(.*)', '\3');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('result_string: ' || result_string);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: А чем другой ответ не устроил? Вроде выглядит попроще.