# Как перечислить все записи в тегах

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Есть строка  `'/home/pc/test'` ,
и слова в тегах `'[/alseko][/logs][/archive]'`
Как получить ожидаемый результат =

```
 [/home/pc/test/alseko][/home/pc/test/logs][/home/pc/test/archive]
```

Мой код, пытаюсь найти:

```
select '[' || '/home/pc/test' ||
       ltrim(substr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]',
              instr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]', '['),
              instr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]', ']')),'[')
from dual
```

Comment: Вам строку придется сначала разобрать на составляющие, получив несколько строк, потом присоединить путь и собрать обратно в одну строку (listagg например). За основу можно взять такой разбор https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/583340/194569

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо распарсить теги в таблицу, и потом заново собрать в строку, например так:

```
with data as (
    select 
    '[/alseko][/logs][/archive]' tags,
    '\[(\/\w+)' pattern,
    '/home/pc/test' prefix 
    from dual
),
tags as (
    select 
        '['||prefix||regexp_substr (tags, pattern, 1, level, null, 1)||']' tag,
        level sort
    from data connect by level <= regexp_count (tags, pattern) 
)   
select listagg (tag) within group (order by sort)
from tags
;
```

Вывод:

> [/home/pc/test/alseko][/home/pc/test/logs][/home/pc/test/archive]

Answer (score 0):

Получился сделать через цикл, сперва определил количество вхождений

```
Declare
vn_count_paths Integer;
vc_paths varchar(1024);
vc_FtpDir varchar(1024);
begin
vn_count_paths:= length('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]')-LENGTH(REPLACE('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]','['));
dbms_output.put_line('Size: ' || vn_count_paths);
for i in 1 .. vn_count_paths
loop
  vc_paths:= vc_paths||'['||'/home/pc/test'||ltrim(substr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]',instr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]','[',1,i)+1,
                                                                                      instr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]',']',1,i)-
                                                                                      instr('[/alseko][/logs][/archive]','[',1,i)-1),'[')||']';
end loop;
vc_FtpDir := '['||'/home/pc/test'||']'||vc_paths;
dbms_output.put_line('vc_FtpDir: ' || vc_FtpDir);
end;
```